# Filter angular material combo box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am dynamically adding multiple combo boxes. If a value in the previously existing combo box is selected I am removing it from the array. The end result must me unique values selected in the combo boxes. I decided to achieve that by filtering out previously existed values. Is this the right approach? 
So far my filter doesn't work.

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in $ctrl.inputFilterRows">
    <md-select ng-model="choice.name">
        <md-option ng-repeat="filter in choice.filters" value="{{filter.value}}"   | filter:filterTest()>
            {{filter.value}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>

<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.addFilter()">ADD FILTER</md-button>
```

Controller:

```
var filtersArray = [
    { value: 'Filter1' },
    { value: 'Filter2' },
    { value: 'Filter3' }
];

$scope.filterTest = function () {
    return function (item) {
        if (item.value === 'Filter3') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
};



self.addFilter = function () {
    var index = self.inputFilterRows.length;
    var newItemNo = index + 1;
    self.inputFilterRows.push({ 'name': 'inputFilter' + newItemNo, 'input': '' });

    self.inputFilterRows[index].filters = filtersArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and what I was missing was to use the correct filter. Maybe this post can help you:

[AngularJS doesn't work with 'multiple' flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404174/angularjs-doesnt-work-with-multiple-flag/53405115?noredirect=1#comment93696815_53405115)